# Python TypeError: Incorrect padding when write to image

Tags: python, base64

I tired with this error. this is encoding base64 http://pastebin.com/16KSrNuL and i try to decode into image using this code

```
wf = open('/Users/me/base.txt', 'w')
wf.write(data.get('base64'))
wf.close()

fp = open('/Users/me/base_result.png', 'wb')
fp.write(base64.b64decode(open('/Users/me/base.txt', 'rb').read()))
fp.close()
```

in my case, i trying post data json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the leading string i.e *data:image/png;base64,* to get the *base64* encoded data:

```
with open("/Users/me/base.txt") as f, open("/Users/me/base_result.png","wb") as out:
    out.write(f.read().split(",",1)[1].decode("base-64"))
```

When you do you get:

[image]

Obviously the leading substring is not base64 encoded.